# Jasper / DynamicJasper: How to invert Column Headers

Tags: dynamic, header, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I have a Jasper report with the following output format:

```
    Item  |  Price  |  Quantity
   ----------------------------
     1        100        5
     2        150        8
     3        200        11
```

How do I make that table to this format:

```
     Item         1      2       3

     Price       100    150     200  

     Quantity     5       8       11
```

The column headers have now become row headers.

I'm actually using DynamicJasper, but of course, it's still relies on Jasper.

What special setting or property should I set to achieve the format I'm looking for.

Also, what do you call this format? Inverted Headers? Inverted Columns? It's hard to Google this issue since the keywords I'm using doesn't seem to be correct. Google always gives me a different answer.

Comment: So far I haven't find any satisfactory solution for this issue. Maybe it's not really possible. I had to use Apache POI to be able to format my report.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if Crosstabs serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested before, either check out crosstab, or you can check their CrosstabBuilder/LayoutManager classes and probably override/extend some to adopt to your needs